# How can I plot these straight lines in a picture?

Tags: plotting, procedural-programming

### How can I plot these straight lines **in a picture**?

```
min = 10;
max = 40;
l = 12;
d = 5;
p = 0.5;
x1 = l/((1/min - 1/max)/(1/max));
k = 1/(max*x1);
n = d/2*min;
Do[Plot[{(i + p/2)*x, (i - p/2)*x}, {x, x1, l}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Black}}], {i, -n, n}]
```

---

Should I use Table?I want to overlay lines into an image.But I don't know how to do it. Thank you.

---

Emm,I solve the half of problem.But now I can only get the half of the picture.
[image]

Comment: I'm afraid *"in a picture"* is ambiguous, this need clarification. It's not clear if you want to export into an image files or overlay lines into an image, nor if is many lines in a single image or one line per image. or probably something different. Please [edit] your question to clarify, use the *comments section* only for comments.

Comment: And by the way, welcome to Mma.SE. Thanks for taking the [tour]. Be sure you have learned about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Is best to [edit] if improvable, or to show due diligence, give context, include minimal working example of code and data. Thanks for using [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX). By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind share what you have learned.

Comment: I’m sorry for my expression.Thank you.

Comment: We understand that explaining may be difficult, there is no need to be sorry, it's fine. We just need as much information as possible to understand what is that you need exactly. With no information we can only guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lines = Show[Table[Plot[{(i + p/2)*x, (i - p/2)*x}, {x, x1, l}, 
        Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Black}}, PlotStyle -> None], {i, -n, n}], 
        AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> False]; 

picture = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
```

[`Rasterize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html) `lines` with a transparent background and resize it to have the same size as `picture`:

```
rasterizedlines = ImageResize[Rasterize[lines,
   ImageResolution -> 300, Background -> None], 
  ImageDimensions[picture]]
```

1. You can use [`ImageCompose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageCompose.html) to show `picture` and `rasterizedlines` overlayed:

```
ImageCompose[picture, rasterizedlines]
```

[image]

2. You can raster `lines` as graphics and use it as `Epilog` to `picture`:

```
rasterizedlines2 = Rasterize[lines, "Graphics",
     ImageResolution -> 300, 
     Background -> None,
     ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[picture]]

Show[picture, Epilog -> First[rasterizedlines2]]
```

[image]

3. You can use `picture` as `Prolog` in `Show`:

```
raster = Rasterize[picture, "Graphics"][[1]];
raster[[2]] = {Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]};

Show[lines,  Prolog -> raster]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Module[
 {
  min = 10, max = 40, l = 12, d = 5, p = 0.5, x1, k, n,
  lines,
  image = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Boat"}],
  plot
  },
 x1 = l/((1/min - 1/max)/(1/max));
 k = 1/(max*x1);
 n = d/2*min;
 lines = Flatten@Table[
    {(i + p/2)*x, (i - p/2)*x}
    , {i, -n, n}];
 plot = Plot[
   lines
   , {x, x1, l}
   , Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Black}}
   , PlotStyle -> Array[Hue, Length[lines], {0, 0.8}]
   , PlotTheme -> "Minimal"
   ];
 Overlay[{image, plot}]
 ]
```

[image]